# How can i validate the data before inserting into table?

Tags: express, validation

function bulkinsertion(req,res){

```
var i;
var student = req.body;
var successCount=0 , errorCount=0;

for(i=0;i<student.length;i++){
    models.Student.create(student[i]).then(result =>{
      successCount++;
     }).catch(error =>{
        errorCount++;
     });
} 
res.status(200).json({
    message:"success",
    successCount:successCount
})

console.log(successCount,errorCount);
```

}

I have 3 columns in my table namely Name , Sem , Branch so how can i validate these 3 columns before inserting into the table?

Comment: You can do validation before create student, inside for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can add validations inside the for loop somewhat similar to code below as per your requirements

```
function bulkinsertion(req,res){

var i;
var student = req.body;
var successCount=0 , errorCount=0;

for(i=0;i<student.length;i++){
  if(student.Name && student.Name.length > 5 && student.Sem && student.Branch && student.Branch.length > 3) {
    models.Student.create(student[i]).then(result =>{
      successCount++;
     }).catch(error =>{
        errorCount++;
     });
  }
} 
res.status(200).json({
    message:"success",
    successCount:successCount
})

console.log(successCount,errorCount);
}
```